# Failed to upload an image

Tags: php, html

I made a form at `HTML` with an option to upload an image. The problem is that when I check the `$_FILES` array at the `php` code, it is not found.

The `HTML` form:

```
<form method="POST" action="addProduct.php" onsubmit="return checkValidation()"> 
Image(optional): <input type="file" name="fileImg" accept="image/*" id="fileImg">
<input id="submitProduct" type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Submit product" onclick="checkValidation()"/>
</form>
```

The `checkValidation()` function:

```
function checkValidation(){
    var regex = /\.(jpg|JGP|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF)$/;
    if (($('#fileImg').val()) && (!(regex.test($('#fileImg').val()))))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the `php` code:

```
if(isset($_POST["submitBtn"])){
    if(!(empty($_FILES)))
    {
        if (file_exists('uploads/'.$_FILES["fileImg"]["name"]))
        {
            echo $_FILES["fileImg"]["name"]." already exists. ";
        }
        else
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileImg"]["tmp_name"], 'uploads/'. $_FILES["fileImg"]["name"]);
            $path = $_FILES["fileImg"]["name"];
        }
    }
    else
        $path = 'no_photo.jpg';
```

The problem is that at the php code, it always jumps to the `else` branch (which gives me some default image).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your regex accepts `JGP` images?

Comment: Don't forget to check the file type in PHP since the javascript can easily be skipped. `if($_FILES['fileImg']['type'] == 'image/png' || ...){`

Comment: I showed my regex at the checkValidation() function. I can tell that the function accepts the file, if I'm comparing the file to this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form lacks the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` attribute. Without it, `$_FILES` would always be empty.

Read more about it here: **[What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)**

Comment: sorry, stupid question. I put it in the form and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ErumHannan If you have a *new* question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" this question as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.